# iOS device screen size

Tags: objective-c, swift, uitableview

I want to assign the table view cell height according to device height.
I know that I can fetch the height but can I assign like table view cell height like

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    switch indexPath.section {
      case 0:
        return 0.9 * UIScreen.main.bounds.width + 440 /// i want like lessthan(0.9 * UIScreen.main.bounds.width + 440)
      case 1:
        let episodesCount: CGFloat = 2
        let seasonDetailsHeight: CGFloat = 104
        return 100 * episodesCount + seasonDetailsHeight
      case 2:
        return ((UIScreen.main.bounds.height) / 4)
      default: return 0
    }
  }
```

Comment: yes you can use the heightForRowAt delegate method to set custom height

Comment: I didn't want to fix like 100 etc

Comment: Sorry but i can't understand your question. Could you better explane what you want to do?

Comment: my main issue is that I can not fix my table view row height because there is a field called description which can be a single line or 1000 lines so according to that I want to maximize or minimize my table view cell